# Is there a fast way to jump to the top level?

Tags: star-wars-tiny-death-star

Is there a fast way to navigate to the top level of my tiny death star?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Tapping anywhere on the top bar will jump to the top.  It just happens that you have to avoid the add a level button.  Otherwise, anywhere else you tap will cause this to happen.

On the image below, you can tap anywhere within the red circles.

[image: Game screen]

Answer (score 0):

Yes, simply tap on the Bitizens or the Levels indicators on the top left/right of the screen.

Comment: It is unrelated to the Bitizens or Levels indicators.  Rather it is a function of tapping on the top of the screen.  The exception being if you tap on the add a level button.